# sourceless iframe may be causing issues with SurveyMonkey widget

Tags: javascript, surveymonkey

There are 2 pages that I made to show the problem:
1) http://4-soft.isebox.net/smcx-trouble/with-video-player
2) http://4-soft.isebox.net/smcx-trouble/no-video-player

Page 1 has a video player that uses vidly (http://vid.ly) widget to play video. I believe that this causes the survey to jump to the bottom of the page
Page 2 has no issues and the survey is shown at the right spot

I don't think it's vidly's script, other scripts that use the same technique that we use break SM widget in the same way (audio player, document previewer)...

Does anyone have an idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

SurveyMonkeys' official answer is:

`An option here would be to embed your survey using a method such as an HTML iframe instead of Javascript.`

So that solves the issue, but does not answer why it jumps out.